# ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer with local images

Tags: android, gis, arcgis

I am new to GIS and ArcGIS framework. I'm looking at the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android. I understand ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer uses cached images as base layer to present it on the screen. Those images needs to be made available via a REST service. Is it possible to use this class with locally stored images, say on SD card?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but not with the `ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer` class. Use the `RasterLayer` class instead.

[`ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ags/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.html) is only for ArcGIS cached map services. If you want to display local imagery, use [`RasterLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/RasterLayer.html) instead ([sample code](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/LocalRasterData), [more documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/add-raster-data.htm)). If you want to display a local tile package or compact cache, use [`ArcGISLocalTiledLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ags/ArcGISLocalTiledLayer.html) instead. If you're not sure which type of layer to use, look at the [documentation on layer types](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/layer-types.htm).

Comment: How you create tile package or compact cache?

Comment: See [how to create a tile package in ArcMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/how-to-create-a-tile-package.htm). You make the tile package in ArcMap and copy it onto your device. That's the easy way. If you get paid more to spend more hours writing code, you can instead [create an offline map in Android](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/create-an-offline-map.htm) (look at the part about creating a basemap; you can create a tile package or compact cache, which both behave the same in Android).